# Finding $\phi$ so that we have $3$ equal sets

Tags: trigonometry, geometric-progressions

> Find all angles $\phi$, if any, for which
>
> the set $S=\left \{ \sin(\phi),\sin(2\phi),\sin(4\phi) \right \}$,
>
> the set $C=\left \{ \cos(\phi),\cos(3\phi),\cos(9\phi) \right \}$,
>
> and the set $T=\left \{ \tan(\phi),\tan(4\phi),\tan(16\phi) \right \}$
>   to be three equal sets.

What I have noticed; in $S$, the angles can be arranged to be in geometric progression. Similarly in $C$ and $T$, but I do not know how is that useful.

I could not even start solving this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that then $$\sin(\phi)=\cos(\phi)=\tan(\phi)$$ and so on?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner sorry dear, can you explain what do you mean? The order of the elements in each set may be rearranged. So for example the set {a,b,c}, the set {b,a,c}, the set {b,c,a}, the set {a,c,b}, ... are the same.

Answer (score -1):

Just, consider three cases:
$$\sin\theta=\cos\theta,$$

$$\sin\theta=\cos3\theta$$ and
$$\sin\theta=\cos9\theta.$$
I got that we have no such value of $\theta$.

Comment: As there are (exclusive) "or"s connectors between the 3 equations you write, each equation **has** solutions. But the true issue is that there are other constraints to come...

Comment: @Jean Marie It's enough. Tangents are not relevant here. For example, for any solutions of $\sin\theta=\cos\theta$ we can not get even $S=C$.

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?